# JQuery SimplePagination Plugin Adding Carousel Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Well i am trying created carousel mode to that plugin

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Minimal-jQuery-Table-Pagination-Plugin-SimplePagination.html

i add the changePage method and the code final is some like

```
(function($)}{ ...

$.fn.simplePagination = function(options){ ....

    return this.each(function() {...

      function changePage(){
         settings.currentPage = (settings.currentPage % page) + 1;
         update();
     }
     function update()...
   });
}
}(JQuery));
```

my idea is do that in the load page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function daemonTablePaginationTask(){
     $(".some_stable_common_style").changePage();
     setTimeOut(daemonTablePaginationTask(), 1000);
   }
});
```

The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).changePage is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:24
```

the question is could i invoke the method?

Comment: $(".some_stable_common_style").simplePagination().changePage();  Perhaps?

Comment: no work. consider the line return this.each(function()).. as i undertand that line is for each element selector so selector.extension().method is not available maybe selector.method i would think but it does not work either :(